# Is it defined to provide an inverted range to C++ standard algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Consider standard algorithms like, say, `std::for_each`.

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

As far as I can tell, there is actually no requirement placed on the *relative* states of the two `InputIterator` arguments.

Does that mean that the following is technically valid? Or is it undefined? What can I realistically expect it to *do*?

```
std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4};
std::for_each(
   v.begin()+3,  // range [3,0)
   v.begin(),
   [](int){}
);
```

[geordi](http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/geordi/) tells me:

> error: function requires a valid iterator range [__first, __last). [+ 13 discarded lines]

but I can't tell how compliant this debug diagnostic is.

---

I came up with this question when trying to *pedantically* determine how explicit is defined the behaviour of the following:

```
std::vector<int> v; // <-- empty
std::for_each(      // <-- total no-op? stated or just left to implication?
   v.begin(),
   v.end(),
   [](int){}
);
```

Comment: +1. Good question.Never thought about this before.

Comment: **Note:** I do realise that the loop with the `[3,0)` range can never "work" as the first iterator is _advanced_. I also realise that `reverse_iterator`s are the appropriate replacement. But I'm asking about the standard wording when it comes to this [usually broken] code.

Comment: If this became part of the standard, every interviewer would have to throw away a pretty good question.

Comment: @Pete: Note to all interviewers: get throwing.

Comment: Just a thought skipping my mind, I have a distinct feeling that this was perhaps covered in the Josutils book - "C++ Standard Library A Tutorial & Reference".

Comment: Just updated my answer, Indeed the book mentions this, Yet another reason for recommending the Josutils book :)

Comment: It is not valid to provide an inverted range, but empty range is ok. (The last part of your question.) A lot of applications would get a lot more cumbersome if `for_each` had to check for emptiness first.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard explicitly requires the `last` iterator to be *reachable* from the `first` iterator. That means that by incrementing `first` one should be able to eventually hit `last`.

> **24.1 Iterator requirements**
>
> ...
>
> **6** An iterator `j` is called reachable from an iterator `i` if and only if
>   there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression `++i` that
>   makes `i == j`. If `j` is reachable from `i`, they refer to the same
>   container.
>
> **7** Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate
>   on data structures have interfaces that use ranges. A range is a pair
>   of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation.
>   A range `[i, i)` is an empty range; in general, a range `[i, j)` refers to
>   the elements in the data structure starting with the one pointed to by
>   `i` and up to but not including the one pointed to by `j`. Range `[i, j)` is
>   valid if and only if `j` is reachable from `i`. The result of the
>   application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is
>   undefined.

Comment: Makes sense. Where is that stated?

Comment: Ah, there is it. I was focusing on the Algorithms section and overlooked this bit when I scanned through Iterators. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, just to be explicit: when `v` is empty, `for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), ...)` *is* well-defined, i.e., it is ok for `last` to be the same as `first`. This follows from the standard wording because `first` *is* reachable from `first` in a finite sequence of increments, the finite sequence in this case being an empty one.

Answer (score 6):

**The result is Undefined.**

---

**C++03 Standard: 25.1.1 For each** and
**C++11 Standard: 25.2.4 For each**
states:

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

> 1 Effects: **Applies f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range [first, last)**, starting
>   from first and proceeding to last - 1

While another section defines the valid range `[first,last)` as:

**C++03 Standard:  24.1 Iterator requirements** and
**C++11 Standard:  24.2.1 Iterator requirements**

**Para 7** for both:

> Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data structures have interfaces that use ranges.A range is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation.  A range [i, i) is an empty range; in general, a range [i, j) refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the one pointed to by i and up to but not including the one pointed to by j. **Range [i, j) is valid if and only if j is reachable from i.  The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is undefined.**

---

Having remembered of reading this somewhere, just browsed through:

*C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference - By Nicolai Josutils*

This finds a mention in:

> **5.4.1  Ranges**
>   The caller must ensure that the first and second arguments define a *valid* range. This is the case if the end of the range is *reachable* from the beginning by iterating through the elements. **This means, it is up to the programmer to ensure that both iterators belong to the same container and that the beginning is not behind the end. If this is not the case, the behavior is undefined and endless loops or forbidden memory access may result**.

Comment: \*cough\* question is tagged `c++11` :)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Ahh, Darn I need to get used to referring n3290 and C++11, Seems I am still in C++03! Thanks though I updated the section details for both.

Comment: Being overly pedantic, but if a bidirectional iterator is being used, wouldn't that mean the the range is, in fact, valid? The `for_each` algorithm is iterating in the wrong direction, but j is reachable from i if it goes the other way.

Comment: @dauphic: The previous paragraph states it; reachable-ness considers increments only.

Comment: **Too** much **of** bold **text** is **not** pleasing **to** the **eye**. Please use it less. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: That is *your* perspective, not necessarily everyone thinks the same.

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean that the following is technically valid? Or is it
>   undefined? What can I realistically expect it to do?

No it is not. Your code would exhibit undefined behavior when `for_each` increments the iterator and that iterator would be pointing to `end` and there is nothing to dereference(Well, it is enough to get undefined behavior at this point, so there is no point talking about *past end*)!

Answer (score 2):

This is explained by section 24.1 of the standard, "Iterator Requirements":

> An iterator `j` is called *reachable* from an iterator `i` if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression `++i` that makes `i == j`. If `j` is reachable from `i`, they refer to the same container.
>
> …
>
> Range `[i, j)` is valid if and only if `j` is reachable from `i`. The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is undefined.

So `v.begin() + 3` is reachable from `v.begin()`, but not the reverse. So `[v.begin()+3, v.begin())` is not a valid range, and your call to `for_each` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The standard defines complexity constraints for the functions taking ranges. In the specific case of `for_each` (25.2.4 in the C++ standard):

> *Complexity*: Applies `f` exactly `last - first` times

So it's effectively a no-op in your example.

Comment: Effectively, yea. I suppose this is about as explicit as I can hope for, really. Cheers.