# Is it defined to provide an empty range to C++ standard algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std

Following on from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504921/is-it-defined-to-provide-an-inverted-range-to-c-standard-algorithms), **can we *prove* that the standard allows us to pass an empty range to a standard algorithm?**

Paragraph 24.1/7 defines an "empty range" as the range `[i,i)` (where `i` is valid), and `i` would appear to be "reachable" from itself, but I'm not sure that this qualifies as a proof.

In particular, we run into trouble when looking at the sorting functions. For example, `std::sort`:

> Complexity: `O(N log(N))` (where `N` == `last` - `first`) comparisons

Since `log(0)` is generally considered to be undefined, and I don't know what `0*undefined` is, could there be a problem here?

---

<sup>(Yes, ok, I'm being a bit pedantic. Of course no self-respecting *stdlib* implementation would cause a practical problem with an empty range passed to `std::sort`. But I'm wondering whether there's a potential hole in the standard wording here.)</sup>

Comment: Two SO users need to read the `language-lawyer` tag wiki: «Typical questions concern gaps between "what will usually work in practice" and "what the spec actually guarantees".»

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't seem *much* room for question. In §24.1/6 we're told:

> An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that makes i == j.

and in $24.1/7:

> Range [i, j) is valid if and only if j is reachable from i.

Since `0` is finite, `[i, i)` is a valid range. §24.1/7 goes on to say:

> The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is
>   undefined.

That doesn't go quite so far as to say that a valid range guarantees defined results (reasonable, since there are other requirements, such as on the comparison function) but certainly seems to imply that a range being empty, in itself, should not lead to UB or anything like that. In particular, however, the standard makes an empty range just another valid range; there's no real differentiation between empty and non-empty valid ranges, so what applies to a non-empty valid range applies equally well to an empty valid range.

Comment: Indeed. I think that your answer agrees with my conclusions thus far, and it certainly seems to be as thorough as anything I can come up with.

Answer (score 10):

Big-O notation is defined in terms of the limit of the function. An algorithm with *actual* running time `g(N)` is `O(f(N))` if and only if <strike>`lim N→∞ g(N)/f(N)` is a non-negative real number</strike> `g(N)/f(N)` is less than some positive real number `C` for all values `N` greater than some constant `k` (the exact values of `C` and `k` are immaterial; you just have to be able to find *any* `C` and `k` that makes this true). (thanks for the correction, Jesse!)

You'll note that the *actual* number of elements is not relevant in big-O analysis. Big-O analysis says nothing about the behavior of the algorithm for small numbers of elements; therefore, it does not matter if `f(N)` is defined at `N=0`. More importantly, the *actual* runtime behavior is controlled by a *different* function `g(N)`, which may well be defined at `N=0` even if `f(0)` is undefined.

Comment: OK, so there's no issue with the complexity requirements, and we can just lean on the fact that the range satisfies all stated iterator requirements?

Comment: I can't speak to the standard's wording as I don't have a copy of the standard, sorry.

Comment: OK; that's what I'm after, really.

Comment: To be pedantic (since the OP was as well :), Big-O notation is not about the limit; `g(N)` is `O(f(N))` *on the range* `I` if there is some positive constant `C` such that `g(N) <= C f(N)` for all `N` in `I`. So there really *is* something to say about `N = 0`, if the standard wanted to. (And you can replace the range `I` with "for large N", meaning, there is some range `[N_0, infinity)`, which is presumably what the standard means by complexity)

Comment: By the way, the main distinction I'm trying to draw is that the limit of `g(N)/f(N)` may not exist (it just needs to have an upper limit).

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the relevant answer given by @bdonlan, note also that `f(n) = n * log(n)` does have a well-defined limit as `n` goes to zero, namely `0`. This is because the logarithm diverges more slowly than any polynomial, in particular, slower than `n`. So all is well :-)

Comment: However, there's still an issue with, for example, `lower_bound`, whose complexity requirement is "at most `log2(last-first) + O(1)` comparisons". This doesn't use O-notation for the logarithmic part, so @bdonlan's argument doesn't apply; and `log2(n)` doesn't have a limit as `n` goes to zero. The best we can do here is argue that `log2(0)` is negative (even though it's undefined), and (if we're talking about C++11) invoke 17.5.1.4/6 ("If the formulation of a complexity requirement calls for a negative number of operations, the actual requirement is zero operations.")

Comment: @Mike: OK, fair enough, though of course in reality there wasn't any issue to begin with, since big-O notation describes asymptotic behaviour, so the behaviour on any bounded interval is irrelevant. Thanks for pointing this out, though :-)