# container.erase(first,last) where first == last in STL containers

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a defined behavior for container.erase(first,last) when first == last in the STL, or is it undefined?

Example:

```
std::vector<int> v(1,1);
v.erase(v.begin(),v.begin());
std::cout << v.size(); // 1 or 0?
```

If there is a Standard Library specification document that has this information I would appreciate a reference to it.

Comment: Do you mean the STL? or do you mean the standard library?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: The subset of the library that deals with templates, I guess.

Comment: You can find exact documentation in the standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Comment: More descriptive documentation can be found at SGI by the original author of the STL: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl

Comment: PlasmaHH: in this context the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it defined to provide an empty range to C++ standard algorithms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505267/is-it-defined-to-provide-an-empty-range-to-c-standard-algorithms)

Comment: Tomalak: *sigh*: search for "erase" on this page: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html (it's the original STL documentation). Please stop being childish about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is well defined.

It is a No-op(No-Operation). It does not perform any erase operation on the container as end is same as begin.

The relevant Quote from the Standard are as follows:

**C++03 Standard:  24.1 Iterator requirements** and
**C++11 Standard:  24.2.1 Iterator requirements**

**Para 6 & 7** for both:

> An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that makes i == j. If j is reachable from i, they refer to the same container.
>
> Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data structures have interfaces that use ranges.A range is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation.  A range [i, i) is an empty range; in general, a range [i, j) refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the one pointed to by i and up to but not including the one pointed to by j. Range [i, j) is valid if and only if j is reachable from i.  The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is undefined.

Comment: It does at least a comparison, though.

Comment: @phresnel: Ofcourse NO-OP is always w.r.t caller. It performs No visible operation for the user.

Comment: It may become visible with iterator traits. (However, as this is on the borderline of pedantry (but is not pedantry as for the possibility of becoming visible), I don't have any thought of downvoting you and I won't commit doing so) (and my definition of no-op slightly varies from yours, but that's for the fact that nobody standardized that term :/)

Answer (score 4):

That would erase nothing at all, just like other algorithms that operate on `[, )` ranges.

Even if the container is empty I think that would still work because `begin() == end()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly defined. It removes all elements from `first` to `last`, including `first` and excluding `last`. If there are no elements in this range (when `first == last`), then how much are removed? You guessed it, none.

Though I'm not sure what happens if `first` comes after `last`, I suppose this will invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

*Conceptually*, there is an ordinary loop from `begin` to `end`, with a simple loop condition that checks if the iterator is `end` already, like this:

```
void erase (iterator from, iterator to) {
    ...
    while (from != to) erase (from++);
    ...
}
```

(however, implementations may vary). As you see, if `from==to`, then there is no single iteration of the loop body.