# Why doesn't the standard allow std::for_each to have well-defined behavior on invalid random access iterator ranges?

Tags: c++, stl, foreach, iterator, range

In this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504921/is-it-defined-to-provide-an-inverted-range-to-c-standard-algorithms)  it was explained that std::for_each has undefined behavior when given an invalid iterator range [first, last) (i.e. when last is not reachable by incrementing first).

Presumably this is because a general loop `for(auto it = first; it != last; ++it)` would run forever on invalid ranges. But for random access iterators this seems an unnecessary restriction because random access iterators have a comparison operator and one could write explicit loops as `for(auto it = first; it < last; ++it)`. This would turn a loop over an invalid range into a no-op.

So my question is: why doesn't the standard allow std::for_each to have well-defined behavior on invalid random access iterator ranges? It would simplify several algorithms which only make sense on multi-element containers (sorting e.g.). Is there a performance penalty for using operator<() instead of operator!=() ?

Comment: are you looking for an answer or discussion on this?

Comment: There are proper answers to this question (+1). So, it does fit on SO, and the current three responses do as well. But indeed, please avoid non-answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This would turn a loop over an invalid range into a no-op.

You seem to be saying that `operator<` should always return `false` for two random-access iterators that are not part of the same range. That's the only way your specified loop would be a no-op.

It doesn't make sense for the standard to specify this. Remember that *pointers* are random-access iterators. Think about the implementation burden for pointer operations, and the general confusion caused to readers, if it were defined that the following code print "two":

```
int a[5];
int b[5]; // neither [a,b) nor [b,a) is a valid range
if ((a < b) || (b < a)) {
    std::cout << "one\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "two\n";
}
```

Instead, it is left undefined so that people won't write it in the first place.

Comment: That's very insightful and precisely the answer to the misconception underlying my question. I was simply thinking of begin + N is "obviously" past end if there are less than N elements in the container. But this would require that an iterator knows that it came from an advance(it, N) on a valid iterator it, and this would be very expensive to keep track of.

Answer (score 4):

> This would turn a loop over an invalid range into a no-op.

That's not necessarily the case.

One example of an invalid range is when `first` and `last` refer to different containers. Comparing such iterators would result in undefined behaviour in at least [some cases](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/ARR36-C.+Do+not+subtract+or+compare+two+pointers+that+do+not+refer+to+the+same+array).

Comment: I know, but why? Random access iterator can detect whether the range is invalid by using comparison. The undefined behavior is unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: @rhalbersma: "Random access iterator can detect whether the range is invalid by using comparison". This is false. It is UB to invoke `operator<` on two random-access iterators that are not in the same range. The rest of your argument falls because the premise does.

Comment: @rhalbersma random access iterator may or may not be able to detect if the range is invalid.  Don't forget, `T*` is a valid random access iterator.  And for two `T*`, `p1 < p2` does **not** mean that all `pi` between them are valid.

Comment: OK, thanks, I understand now. Any for_each(begin + N, end, fun) is only safe with at least N elements in the container, and with less elements there is not a no-op but undefined behavior.

Comment: @rhalbersma: in that case the UB occurs as soon as you do `begin()+N`, if there aren't at least `N` elements. It makes no difference which comparison you use in the algorithm, since the addition is already invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's the general policy.  All using `<` would allow is things
like:

```
std::for_each( v.begin() + 20, v.begin() + 10, op );
```

Even with `<`, passing an invalid iterator, or iterators from different
containers, is undefined behavior.